# Open Redirect Action in new window with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have one [post] action which return Redirect(url). I want to open this response in new tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <button id="aButton" >Submit</button>
}
```

Javascript using jQuery:

```
$('#aButton').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this).parent('form');
        form.attr('target', '_blank');
        form.submit();
    });
```

This way you can leave your action as is and if you want to submit other form variables you can if you include them within your form.

The above solution is unobtrusive and works if javascript is disabled.

Comment: <input type="button" title="Submit" value="Confirmed" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("", "", new { targe="_blank" })'" />

Comment: This is one is the easiest one solution.

Comment: It is the easiest but it is also intrusive and ties your html to your javascript. The above solution is not only unobtrusive but also does not break if javascript is disabled. @Pritam

Answer (score 3):

Is it mandatory to use javascript? :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action","Controller",FormMethod.Post, new { target = "_blank" }))
{
    <input type="submit" value="clickme"/>
}
```

Comment: Are you redirecting to another action method?

Comment: Yes in redirect you can put any action method name.

Comment: Then why my answer does not help?